# Discord.js Bot reply to message with embed?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

```
  client.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.content === "+help") {
  msg.reply("  const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(0x0099FF)
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor({ name: 'Some name', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addFields({ name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true })
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'Some footer text here', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png' });
"
  });
    }
  })
```

i want a simple help menu for my bot if someone says "+help". but in an embed. I have no idea and this code probably won't work.

Comment: You've placed all your code as a string. Take it out and send `exampleEmbed`

Answer (score 0):

You're replying to the message with the code, literally - move the code outside the `message.reply()` call. Also, you have to import the embed builder. (https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(0x0099FF)
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor({ name: 'Some name', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addFields({ name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true })
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'Some footer text here', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png' });

msg.reply({embeds: [embed]});
```

You put it all as a string, if the user used your command. It will only reply a  plain string, do an embed array and use it to reply